# filtering by several values at once

Tags: javascript

please tell me how to use the filter to catch several values at once, provided that the value that we are looking for is dynamic

```js
var tags = ['cat', 'animal'] //this will be a dynamic value the user will enter

var list = [
{
  tags: 'cat, kitty, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'pet, animal, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'tiger, kitty, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'cat, kitty, animal, big cat'
}];

list.filter(item => {
  return item.tags.includes(/* need to filter only those where there are both values from the array tags */)
})
```

Comment: @epascarello no, I want to use it in the project, here I just made an example for easier so as not to throw a lot of code from the project here

Comment: so the code should be `return tags.every(..your includes logic..)`

Comment: @David I don’t know how to do this with multiple dynamic values, I only know how to filter with static values even if there are several, but I don’t know with dynamic

Comment: @epascarello And if the array "tags" is dynamic how to do it through every?

Comment: um, every loops over it.... so if it is dynamic it will use what is there.

Comment: @epascarello So every will return only true or false, and I need a filtered array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *and* the input tags; i.e. only show the list items that match *all* the tags, then use

```
list.filter(item => tags.every(tag => item.tags.includes(tag));
```

On the other hand, if you want to *or* the input tags; i.e. show the list items that match *any* of the tags, then use

```
list.filter(item => tags.some(tag => item.tags.includes(tag));
```

Comment: Don't work, what is the "tag" maybe "tags" do you mean? and i got error "Unexpected token, expected "," " on second "=>"

Comment: Removed the extra `)`.